An approach to find eigenvectors by finding dependence
I don't understand this theorem of finding eigenvectors by finding dependence. Could someone please explain?
Suppose that $V$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector space. If $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation, then $\{I, T^1,...,T^{n \cdot n}\}$ is linearly dependent in $L(V,V)$. Alternatively, there are non-zero constants such that: $Z = a_{n \cdot n}T^{n \cdot n} + ... + a_2 T^2 + a_1 T^1 + a_0 I$, where $I: V \rightarrow V$ is the identity and $Z: V \rightarrow V$ is the zero map.
I don't really understand why $\{I, T^1,...,T^{n \cdot n}\}$ is linearly dependent here.

Because $n^2 > n-1$ the dimension of $k[T]$ is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial, which is less than $n$ and you have here more than $n+1$ vectors so they are linearly dependent.

EDIT: There is a simpler explanation here; the space $\mathcal{L}(V)$ has dimension $n^2$ and here you have $n^2+1$ vectors in your family, thus it is necessarily linearly dependent. The paragraph below is a refinement (stronger but not needed in your case). Keep it in mind for next year!

As I stated in my comment, the dimension of
$$k[T]=\{p(T),\,p \in k[X]\}$$
is $\deg \Pi_T$ (the minimal polynomial of $T$).
You can easily see that by studying the algebra homomorphism:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
k[X] & \to & \mathcal{L}(V)\\
p & \mapsto & p(T)
\end{array}$$
Its kernel is $\{p \in k[X] \mid p(T) = 0\} = (\Pi_T)$ (all ideals are principal and by definition $\Pi_T$ is the generator) so since its image is $k[T]$, you have an algebra isomorphism
$$k[X]/(\Pi_T) \cong k[T] .$$
You can then deduce $\dim_k k[T] = \deg \Pi_T$, but since $\Pi_T \mid \chi_T$ the characteristic polynomial (since by Cayley-Hamilton, $\chi_T(T)=0$), we have $\deg \Pi_T \leqslant \deg \chi_T = n$, so $\dim_k k[T] \leqslant n$.
Now you have a family of vectors $(I,T,T^2,\dots,T^{n^2})$ in $k[T]$, but since you have $n^2+1 >n$ vectors, they are necessarily linearly dependent.

Sorry I am a first-year student learning linear algebra. This looks too complicated for me to understand...Is there a simpler explanation?

Yes there is a simpler explanation let me write it

Thank you so much!
